# Dynamic Confirmation email for forms (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a wordpress form and there are 3 possible emails that i wish this to be sent to depending on one of the choices they choose. Is there a way to have dynamic email confirmations depending on choices in the form.
Example - working on a form for a catering service for 13 stores. There are 3 district managers for the 13 stores. In the form the user selects what store they wish to be catered from and i am wondering if there is a way for me to set it up so that once the form is completed the corresponding district managers gets an email.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can use a [dropdown tag field with pipes](http://brandoncoppernoll.com/how-to-use-pipes-in-contact-form-7/).